# How to Store diffrent data type names in one structure in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have created different type of objects in trait pipe[In,Out] and I want to pipe those objects dynamically.pipeline order can be change dynamically 
I have stored those objects in Array of Any type I want to cast those objects dinamically.

```
trait Pipe[In, Out] {

  def apply(rdd: RDD[In]): RDD[Out]

  def |[Final](next: Pipe[Out, Final]): Pipe[In, Final] = {
    val self = this
    new Pipe[In, Final] {
      def apply(rdd: RDD[In]) = next(self(rdd))
    }
  }

}
val timestampConverter = new Pipe[String, String]
val summaryBuilder = new Pipe[String, String]
val seperatedRdd = new Pipe[String, (String, ArrayBuffer[Double])]

val arrBuf = new ArrayBuffer[Any]()
    arrBuf += timestampConverter
    arrBuf += summaryBuilder
    arrBuf += seperatedRdd

var ss:Any = arrBuf(0)

for(x <- 1 to arrBuf.length){
      ss = ss.asInstanceOf[PreviousType] | x.asInstanceOf[Type]
    }
```

Is there any structure for keep diffrent objects types I want to solve PreviousType and Type above.